# Differential topology, fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: differential-topology

I am reading Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint, in particular page 8-9 about applying regular values to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra. So he defines stereographic projection as $h_{+}: S^{2}-\{(0,0,1)\}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}\times \{0\}$ and also he defines it from the south pole, namely, $h_{-}:S^{2}-\{(0,0,-1)\}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}\times \{0\}.$ Although he says its elementary geometry, I don't understand why the composition $h_{+}h^{-1}_{-}(z)=\frac{z}{|z|^{2}}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you very much.

Comment: What did you come up with for your maps $h_+$ and $h_-$?

Comment: I used the stereographic projection to define $h_{+}(x,y,z)=\Big(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z},0\Big)$ and $h_{-}(x,y,0)=\Big(\frac{2x}{|z|^{2}+1},\frac{2y}{|z|^{2}+1},\frac{1-|z|^{2}}{1+|z|^{2}}\Big),$ but I think Milnor avoids this and uses something more elementary in geometry. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your definition of $h_-$ can not be correct, the 3rd coordinate has to be $0$. Or do you mean $h_-^{-1}$?

Comment: Probably you should take polar coordinates in $R^2$. Then it is kind of obvious that $h_+h_-^{-1}$ preserves the $\phi$-coordinate and you have to argue that the circle of radius $r$ in one chart corresponds to the circle of radius $\frac{1}{r}$ in the other.

Comment: He's an arse for calling that "elementary geometry"...